# DISTINCT is not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

SQL query in Ms-Access

```
INSERT INTO tblTmpEventLog( TrackingNumber, PartNumber, PartNumberChgLvl,
                            EnteredBy, EventTypeSelected, EventDate )
SELECT DISTINCT tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber,
       tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber, tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel,
       [Forms]![frmEventLog_Input]![EnteredBy] AS EnteredBy,
       [Forms]![frmEventLog_Input]![EventTypeSelected] AS EventTypeSelected,
       CDate([Forms]![frmEventLog_Input]![EventDate]) AS EventDate
  FROM tblRevRelLog_Detail LEFT JOIN tblEventLog
    ON (tblEventLog.PartNumber =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber)
   AND (tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel)
 WHERE ((([tblRevRelLog_Detail]![RevRelTrackingNumber]) = 
          [Forms]![frmEventLog_Input]![TrackingNumber]))
   AND ((tblEventLog.PartNumber) NOT IN
            (SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber FROM tblEventLog
              WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper'
                AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber =
                         tblRevRelLog_Detail.RevRelTrackingNumber
                AND tblEventLog.PartNumber =  tblRevRelLog_Detail.PartNumber
                AND tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl =  
                         tblRevRelLog_Detail.ChangeLevel
             ));
```

DISTINCT keyword for EnteredBy, EventTypeSelected is not working..I mean, data for these columns is not displaying when I use DISTINCT keyword.

EVENTDATE is working fine, but I do not understand why is it not displaying for EneteredBy and EventTypeSelected columns.

Can anyone tell me how to handle this?

Comment: You've asked 14 questions and chosen an answer for only 33% - start picking answers to your questions.

Comment: You'll need to show the whole query if you want help

Comment: @Jack, OK I will choose from now...

Comment: @mwolfe02, Updated whole query

Comment: BTW I tested with a sample table and form. DISTINCT does not stop form data being returned in a query.

Comment: Have you tested the query without the distinct?

Comment: yes, it is working fine without distinct. But it is displayng all the rows which i do not want. So I am trying to eliminate duplicates by using DISTINCT

Comment: @Remou, NO. It is not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the query can't interpret properly from the form directly as the final data type.  However in your date field, you are wrapping it in a function CDATE( ... ).  So, the SQL engine knows the result type.  I would suggest doing the same for the other fields.  Ex: doing a CAST ( ...your form control... as DateTime ) as OtherColumn, etc... I THINK Access allows casting, but not positive.  Otherwise, pre-pull the form value into a declared data type variable and use THAT variable in the query AS OtherColumn as you are doing.

Additionally to what @Jack mentioned, you can always go back to your account, look at your historical question, and click on whatever answers actually helped / solve your problems.   Some questions never do get answers and that's ok, just give credit to those that DO help.

Comment: Thanks...It is working now.I will pick answers for my old questions now

Comment: It's always a good idea to declare any references to form controls in a SQL statement as parameters. This allows the query optimizer to do a better job, and also enhances reliability (particular if any of the controls are Null).

Answer (score 0):

I have found in the past (I don't remember which old version of Access this was) that if you set the value of a form control in VBA, and then use that control in a query, the query will not see the value you set in VBA.  If the user edits the control normally, the query sees the expected value.  Perhaps that's what happened here.

To work around that, you can declare a VBA function that returns the desired value.  For example, instead of this:

```
SELECT ..., Forms!MainForm!TextEntry AS TextEntry, ... FROM ...
```

use this:

```
SELECT ..., GetTextEntry() AS TextEntry, ... FROM ...
```

along with this:

```
Public Function TextEntry() As Variant
    TextEntry = Forms!MainForm!TextEntry
End Function
```

Comment: You do not need a function, anything that forces a type will do: `SELECT ..., "" & Forms!MainForm!TextEntry`

Comment: No, I mean that I have seen the following behavior (probably in Access 97 -- I couldn't reproduce it in Access 2003 or 2010):  (1) Change a textbox control value from X to Y. (2) Run a query that depends on the textbox control's value.  (3) Observe that the query sees value X rather than value Y.  It was a long time ago.  It might have been before I figured out about the AccessField objects, or some other quirk.